# Amides and Alcohol acidity

Tags: organic-chemistry

Are amides more acidic than alcohols? I thought this regarding a secondary amide and a tertiary alcohol functional group since amides have both electronegative oxygen and nitrogen, compared to alcohol which just has an oxygen

Comment: Their acidities are similar.

Comment: This may assist you  https://owl.oit.umass.edu/departments/OrganicChemistry/appendix/pKaTable.html

Answer (score 2):

> Are amides more acidic than alcohols?

This is very broad question. The very short and general answer would be both have similar acidities (as Mithoron pointed out in his comment elsewhere). To support this statement, there is some evident in the Table provided by [UMass website](https://owl.oit.umass.edu/departments/OrganicChemistry/appendix/pKaTable.html) that mentioned by  Waylander in his comment. For example, the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value for the $\ce{N-H}$ in ehtanamide $(\ce{CH3C(O)NH2})$ is about $17$ $(\ce{CH3C(O)NH2}/\ce{CH3C(O)NH-})$ while that for the $\ce{O-H}$ in ethanol $(\ce{CH3CH2OH})$ is about $16$ $(\ce{CH3CH2OH}/\ce{CH3CH2O-})$. In that account, ethanol is more acidic than ethanamide (about by 10 times). However, the acidity would be all most identical if you add one extra $\ce{CH3}$ group to the carbon bearing $\ce{O-H}$ group on ethanol, making it $2^\circ$-alcohol. For instance, $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of 2-propanol $(\ce{(CH3)2CHOH})$ is about $17.1$. Further, the acidity would be reversed if you add another $\ce{CH3}$ group again to the carbon bearing $\ce{O-H}$ group (to make it $3^\circ$-alcohol. Best example is *tert*-butanol $(\ce{(CH3)3COH})$, $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of which is about $18.0$ (about 10 times less acidic than ethanamide). Based on these examples alone, can you say any alcohol is more acidic than particular amide? The answer is **no**. That's why I suggest that this question is broader than it seems. Thus, I advise OP to narrow down their scope so can give reliable answer.